# Create an instance of an object with the help of function (dynamically), on event triggers

Tags: javascript, function, class, object, instanceof

I want to create an instance of an user Object containing the name, age etc.. prop. I just given a form to be filled by user and with that details i want to create his instance of an object dynamically (with that person own name i.e; user). For that i used function like shown below, but i'm facing this error . Thanks for the help in advance

```
class MainUser{
  constructor(name,age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
  }
}
```

```
function createUser(user, name, age){
  let user = new MainUser(name, age);
}
```

I'm getting this error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'user' has already been declared

Comment: Identiier user already declared? Probably two classes that are called user. Try another name.

Comment: Well, you are declaring `user` once as a parameter of your function and once with `let` as a local variable. What are you trying to achieve with that `createUser` function? How did you intend to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the variable `user` as an parameter in the function-definition of `createUser`, and with `let user` you are trying to re-declare that parameter/variable. You have three options depending on what you try to achieve.

1. rename the `user`-parameter of the function
2. rename the `user` variable for your object inside the function
3. remove the `let` to use the parameter of the function

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
  }
}

let user = null;
function createUser(name, age){
  user = new User(name, age);
}
createUser('Alice', 32);

console.log(user);
```

Another approach you can use:

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
  }
}

function createUser(name, age){
  let userObject = new User(name, age); 
  return userObject;
}
let user = createUser('Bob', 31);

console.log(user);
```

For creating a variable with a dynamic name inside the current scope you can use the following:

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
  }
}

function createUser(user, name, age){
  this[user] = new User(name, age);
  console.log(this[user]);
  console.log(test_user);
}
createUser('test_user', 'Charly', 42);
```

Comment: Thnx for the code, but if i write let user2 then it is going to create the instance statically and for all the entries the object name would be user2
and without the variable let, there is no difference :)

Comment: I've updated the code to make it more clear how the scoping and function-parameters are working.  The first example `createUser()` creates the user-object and assign it to the `user`-variable (note: it is defined outside the function). The second example creates the user-object and returns it to the function-caller so it gets assigned to the `user`-variable

Comment: Thanks for ur concern in solving it but its looking static in the more way..

My simple requirement is I'll create a form and user fills the data...based on the data create an object with the name of the each user (differently) and that too dynamically, when the user submits the data.

Comment: Ok, i think i finally get what you want to achieve. I've added another example to the answer.

Comment: woohh.. Its working fine now.. thnx a lot and sorry for not conveying the question properly before

Comment: @premkatta I'm glad that your problem got solved and your code is now working. As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)